# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var points to a directory that doesn't exist. -- how to clear/unset?

Tags: firebase, gcloud

```
Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to some/path
```

I am trying to setup Firebase emulators and I keep getting this error (screenshot below). I'm out of ideas as to how to find a solution for it. The project no longer exists, so afiak using the `gcloud sdk` won't help since the service accounts listed are only present for active projects. I removed the reference to gcloud from my `.zshrc` file, yet the path is still set somewhere.

Any ideas how I can resolve this? I've gone through about half a dozen gcloud docs that more often than not feel like red-herrings.

[image]

Comment: One way is to delete all emulators at location - ~/.cache/firebase/emulators/ 

Also I have a suspicion, that the error is just a warning. The real issue will be in firestore-debug.log file.

Comment: the `firestore-debug.log` has the following response: "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java."

Comment: which is odd, perhaps I missed a step in the docs that says I need a java runtime

Comment: okay, installed the java runtime and configured a few remaining steps for the firebase emulators. Thanks for setting me on the right path, I thought I was having a gcloud configuration error.

Comment: No problem. Have a good day

Comment: @kevin can you post it as an answer for visibility?

Comment: I don't actually have an answer for that. The real underlying issue was in my `firestore-debug.log`. I needed to install java. That error didn't appear in the log that appears in the screenshot, but when I installed that the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to delete all emulators at location - ~/.cache/firebase/emulators/ Also I have a suspicion, that the error is just a warning. The real issue will be in firestore-debug.log file.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Kevin's answer in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646917/google-application-credentials-env-var-points-to-a-directory-that-doesnt-exist/69800699#comment123107151_69646917): Installing the Java runtime solved the issue.